# Is there a way to log the duration of time of the before and after methods in a Protractor/Jasmine specification?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

The output from my Protractor execution is as follows:

```
[13:51:55] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[13:51:55] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
Spec started
[2017-10-31 13:51:59.710] [DEBUG] protractorLog4js - [spec mapper app]: Before All
[2017-10-31 13:51:59.712] [INFO] protractorLog4js - [LoginLogoutWorkflow]: Using default username and password to login.

  [2017-10-31 13:52:50.406] - spec mapper app

    [2017-10-31 13:52:50.407] - import/export page
      [2017-10-31 13:52:50.407] - √ TC2963: ImportComponentGrid_ShouldDefaultSortBySubmittedDateInDescendingOrder_WhenPageIsLoaded (16 secs)
      [2017-10-31 13:53:03.140] - √ TC2955: ImportComponentAddButton_ShouldImportDoorScheduleData_WhenValidExcelFileIsUsed (13 secs)

Executed 2 of 2 specs SUCCESS in 1 min 3 secs.
[13:53:03] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[13:53:03] I/launcher - chrome #01 passed
```

I see that the overall length of time for the execution was `1 min 3 seconds`, but the tests themselves only take 16 and 13 seconds respectively.  If I subtract the test time I end up with 34 seconds left.  I have `beforeAll`, `beforeEach`, and `afterAll` methods that I assume take up the rest of that time.

I would like to find a configuration that allows for output and time tracking of these setup and teardown methods.  I'm currently using Protractor, jasmine-spec-reporter, and log4js-protractor-appender to produce the output above.  I've dug through protractor and jasmine-spec-reporter's configurations to try to find an option for these types of methods and I've not had much luck finding what I'm looking for.  Thanks for any ideas you might have!

Answer (score 0):

You may implement your own functions to timeit the desired operations.

```
startTime = new Date().getTime();
// any operations or function code which you want to measure
var endTime = new Date().getTime();
var elapsedTime = endTime - startTime;
console.log('elapsedTime = ' + elapsedTime + 'ms');
```